# Making status bar fully transparent on Android 11+

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-statusbar

I want to make the app statusBar fully transparent. I used `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`

It's making statusBar as I want. But it also makes the navigation bar on Top of my content. I used many methods to make the navigation bar not change but failed. There are many answers on the internet, but nothing works. How to make a full transparent statusBar without black shadow and without navigationBar change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't helped by anybody by making the question. But after some month, when making another app, I got the answer of this question and it just worked with my app.

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        //Virtual keyboard is also transparent
        //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

I hope this code will work fine!